# Do I need a transit visa for Serbia?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, pakistani-citizens, serbia

Do I need a transit visa while transiting through the Serbia for USA on a Pakistani passport and valid US visa?

Answer (score 1):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country within 24 hours.

So no, you don't need a visa.